# Spark: Distributed removal/addition of elements in a set?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert a ML algorithm to Spark Scala to take advantage of my cluster's power. The relevant bits of pseudo-code are the following:

```
initialize set of elements

while(set not empty) {

  while(...) { remove a given element from the set }

  while(...) { add a given element to the set }

}
```

Is there any way to parallelize such a thing?

I would intuitively say that this is not implementable in a distributed fashion (the number of iterations being unknown), but I have been reading that Spark allows implementation of iterative ML algorithms.

Here is what I tried so far:

- Originally used a mutable Set and removed/added elements during the loops in simple Scala. It runs correctly, but I feel like the whole code will just be executed on the driver which limits the interest of using Spark?
- Made the set a RDD, and replaced the var during every iteration by a new RDD with subtracted/added element (which I suppose is super heavy?). No error appears but the variable doesn't actually get updated.

  mySetRDD = mySetRDD.subtract(sc.parallelize(Seq(element)))
- Looked up Accumulators for a way to keep a set of elements upated on its content (presence/absence of elements) across multiple executors, but they do not seem to allow things other than simple updates of numerical values.

Comment: In general you can discard accumulators which don't provide strong consistency guarantees when used inside transformations.  The rest depend on a particular problem at hand. Iterative nature is not an issue here.

Comment: I see. Putting accumulators aside then, what kinds of implementation are possible for my set?
I might be wrong but I feel like if I keep my mutable set, the whole execution will just stay totally sequential on one machine, without making use of Spark's power. On the other hand the RDD "update" I tried out does not seem to work.

Comment: There is really not generic answer here. If you cannot express the problem in a different way than moving an __arbitrary element__ from one set to another there is no good reason to use Spark. I mean you can use IndexedRDDs or similar tools but there is no value in that.  Problem you have is an algorithm design not programming itself.

Answer (score 0):

Create PairRDD and then repartitionByKey say x partitions.
After that you can use

PairRdd1.zipPartition() to get the iterator over partition of rdds. Then you can write a function which will work over two iterators to produce third or output iterator.

Since you have repartition the rdd by key you need not keep track of the removals across partitions.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#zipPartitions(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, boolean, scala.Function2, scala.reflect.ClassTag, scala.reflect.ClassTag)

Comment: "you need not keep track of the removals across partitions" I am not sure I get this.

Comment: I meant each partition has distinct elements so you need not worry about the data in other partitions.

Comment: Oh, right! However if the element that needs to be removed is the maximum of the whole set, there isn't really a way to make this work through partitions, is it?

Comment: Do you know the value of the element to be removed ? Or you want to remove the maximum?

Comment: The maximum specifically.

Comment: Use rangepartitioner instead of hashpartitioner and the maximum will be in last partition.